# How to reinstall node_modules after dependabot PR merge

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I am using Dependabot to automatically update my dependencies.

How can I update the local packages to the new version?

Currently, I am deleting the whole `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` to make sure I have the latest version installed.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to delete your `node_modules`. Running `npm install` should upgrade the modules that need upgrading itself.

Comment: Huh, okay I'll double check that. Thanks!